# Drag Vertices - ol2 Modify Control vs. ol3+ Modify Interaction

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

In OpenLayers 2, clicking a geometry with an active modify control running, created a drag vertice on every edge of the geometry which could be used to modify the geometry by dragging.

In OpenLayers 3+ with the modify interaction, things are different. Clicking a geometry instantly activates one vertice only that can be dragged.

Can I obtain the ol2 behaviour in ol3+ as well?

Answer (score 1):

It can be imitated.  You woould need to use a custom style to style the vertices and midpoints similar to https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/polygon-styles.html then use a custom `condition` function which checks proximity to those points.

The OpenLayers 2 example http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/modify-feature.html

The standard OpenLayers 4 example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/snap.html

A custom version of the OpenLayers 4 example https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/NWKvLdG